# What does ID195-672 <24> CAK1 mean

Tags: kodak

The code ID195-672 <24> CAK1 is printed in the back of a photo that I am trying to date.

Comment: Check here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105313/34947 , here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/123048/34947 , https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96962/34947

Comment: Also here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94352/34947

Answer (score -1):

Typically film was taken to a drugstore or camera shop to be developed and printed. Most popular were films that developed up as a negative image. Drug stores and camera stores passed these films to regional photofinisher who likely was receiving hundreds if not thousands of rolls of film a day.

Identification of each roll and what services were wanted was no easy task. The roll of film received an ID number that linked it to the original envelope with name and instructions. The developed roll of film had a adhesive label applied.

Next the film goes to a printing station. This machine exposes the negative onto photo paper. To identify each picture and tie it back to the origional envelope, the photo printer has a back printer that applies the code you are asking about.

This code ties the print to a specific printing station. Moreover, the printer has advanced logic, it scanned the negative and automatically applied exposure correctios that greatly reduce the make-over percentage.

When the negatives and prints are united with the original bag, the prints are inspected. Substandard prints that can be improved are returned to the printer that printed them. The code tells what corrections were applied. Now the printer operator examines the substandard print and manually applies a different correction. Thes are punched and the negative is reprinted.

The code may have a date included but I cannot glean that for you.